# Second SQL query with value from textfield

Tags: sql, .net, vba, visual-studio, odbc

I've got a table adapter with a simple SQL query that works fine.

So when I hit my button this happens(I just changed the names to something random):

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
Me.MyDataTableTableAdapter.Fill(Me.MyData.MyDataTable)
End Sub
```

And this executes this SQL statement:

```
SELECT TABLE1.COL1, TABLE1.COL2, TABLE1.COL3, TABLE2.COL1, TABLE2.COL2, TABLE2.COL3
FROM LIB.TABLE2 TABLE,
     LIB.TABLE1 TABLE
WHERE TABLE2.COL2 = TABLE1.COL2
  AND (TABLE1.COL1 = '5458767')
```

It works great and outputs a table with the wanted information. But I also want to be able to change the order number from a text field. So now I got a text field called "CustomerOrder".

I am then adding another query to my dataset:

```
SELECT TABLE1.COL1, TABLE1.COL2, TABLE1.COL3, TABLE2.COL1, TABLE2.COL2, TABLE2.COL3
FROM LIB.TABLE2 TABLE,
     LIB.TABLE1 TABLE
WHERE TABLE2.COL2 = TABLE1.COL2
  AND (TABLE1.COL1 = '@CustomerOrder')
```

And my new query is called FillByCustomer:

```
Me.MyDataTableTableAdapter.FillByCustomer(Me.MyData.MyDataTable)
```

But the variable "CustomerOrder" is just empty. How can I pass the value from the textfield "CustomerOrder.text" to my SQL statement? So I basically want to to write the order number in my text field "CustomerOrder" and use my Button1 to execute this and update my table with the information corresponding to the entered order number.

Looking forward to some suggestions.

EDIT: See answer below. I made a mistake in my SQL statement.

Comment: Both queries are invalid and should not execute...

Comment: How can they be invalid when I'm using the query manager?

Comment: `TABLE` is a reserved word, must be delimited if used as identifier. (e.g. table alias.) You're also having that table alias twice... Which dbms accepts that?

Comment: Sorry. That's the part I changed. The real name is not TABLE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made at mistake in my SQL statement. I'm using ODBC, so instead for @ I should use ?. And then it works.